# searching records in rails include belongs_to or has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, where-clause, rails-activerecord, has-many, belongs-to

I have two models, products and producers. A producer can have many products and a product belongs to a producer.
I'm now trying to get all records from a search query like this:

```
@products = Product.where("name like ? OR product.producer.name like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%", "%#{params[:q]}%")
```

This should return all products where product.name or product.producer.name is like the search string. Is there a short rails way?

Comment: Yes it is. If you need to use like you shoulld read some about full text search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
Product.includes(:producer)
        .where('products.name LIKE ? OR producers.name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:q]}%", "%#{params[:q]}%")
```

You can make a scope with it:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :with_name_like, lambda { |name| 
            includes(:producer).where('products.name LIKE ? OR producers.name LIKE ?', "%#{name}%", "%#{name}%") 
  }
```

And use it like this:

```
@products = Product.with_name_like('Chair')
```